# Windows Media Center does not have an Internet connection

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, windows-media-center

I have a stable Internet connection but when I try to connect with Windows Media Center it gives an error:

> You must be connected to the Internet to use this feature. Check your Internet connection and try again.

[image]

What is the cause of this error?

Additionally when I try to set up the connection manually Media Center crashes with an error log as:

> Event Info: ERROR: SqmApi.Set failed (LogId=30); Win32 GetLastError
>   returned 10000A08 
> Process: DefaultDomain
> Object Name: Media
>   Center Guide

Comment: no answer ? please it is urgent ...

Comment: Please provide more info: What type of connection to your router? What does your ipconfig look like? what happens when you ping google? what happens when you ping 74.125.230.145?

Comment: I have an ethernet connection and i can successfully ping both google and 74.125.230.145, my internet connection is just perfectly fine but there is a problem with media center.